# Auto-typing of a Column in a HtmlProvider<...>.Table.Row>

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am using `FSharp.Data` `HTMLProvider` to extract table rows:

```
let [<Literal>] URL = "../DailyResultsType.html"
type RawResults = HtmlProvider<URL>
let results = RawResults.Load(URL).Tables
let dailySeq =
    results.Table2.Rows
    |> Seq.tail
```

Looping over the rows (`row` is a `seq<HtmlProvider<...>.Table2.Row>`):

```
for row in dailySeq do
    printfn "%A" row
```

Results in:

```
(1, nan, nan, 2)
(1, nan, nan, 3)
~~~
```

Columns like #2 and #3 are getting auto-typed by the provider as `decimal` and `double` as the HTML contain strings such as "$12.00" or "$12".

- Can I dynamically change the type of those columns *within* the type returned from the `HtmlProvider<URL>` at runtime (i.e. from double to string) (but I would *prefer* a numeric type so I can Deedle the results)
- Or apply a runtime string transformation to the values in those columns to remove the non-digit characters so they are valid decimal/double/int types...
- Or am I missing a basic concept (most likely as I am a F# noobie)

Comment: Can you please share a small HTML file that reproduces the problem?

Comment: does it return nan on all values? the typeprovider will replace with nan some missing values. You can filter with `Double.isNan`. Decimal and double are numeric types... You can use `string` to convert it. Best would be an example html in gist or a link.

Comment: @s952163 Yes, they are all `nan` (500+ rows) * 60+ pages . I'll try to create a publishable sample page that reproduces the issue... So far it is easier just to pre-parse the pages and then feed them to the `HTMLProvider`

Comment: I think you will get all `nan` when the column contains both some monetary value and N/As.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to set PreferOptionals to true, that way the N/As will become null, and the rest of the number decimals.

`type HtmlType = HtmlProvider<URL,PreferOptionals=true>` or
`type HtmlType = HtmlProvider<URL,PreferOptionals=true,Culture="en-US">`

```
let results = HtmlType.Load(URL)
results.Tables.Table1.Rows
// val it : HtmlProvider<...>.Table1.Row [] =
// [|("Jill", "Smith", Some 50.0M); ("Eve", "Jackson", Some 100000M);
// ("John", "Doe", Some 100M); ("Jane", "Doe", null)|]
```

If there is no missing value in the table, and I omit PreferOptionals and Culture then I get the following output:

```
//val it : HtmlProvider<...>.Table1.Row [] =
//[|("Jill", "Smith", 50.0M); ("Eve", "Jackson", 100000M);
//("John", "Doe", 100M)|]
```

By the way, I might be wrong but I couldn't find anything where you can specify the schema of the table like in the csv provider. So once I get the data out I would just directly work with the tuple array, if there are not that many elements that should be straightforward. You can use `string` if necessary or pipe it directly to Deedle (`rows |> Frame.ofRecords`).

I used the following sample table.

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>$50.0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td> 
    <td>$100,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jane</td>
    <td>Doe</td> 
    <td>N/A</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but there are no `N/A`'s in those columns, all the values are prefix by $ symbol and are thousand comma formatted with and without decimal (cents) value. I've manually reviewed each table row to confirm.

Comment: In that case some sort of sample would be helpful. But either way I think we established that parsing the html table is an iffy endevaour with the type provider so you might be better off doing it outside. I will see if mixing decimal and non-decimal will make any difference. However using a $ symbol should give you a decimal value (M). If not than it's a locale issue. Is there any way you could set locale to US for example in the type provider? The parameter is `Culture`.